# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'nums' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
spisok_for_lvl_1 = []
file = open('lvl.txt')
for line in file:
    line = line.strip().split(',')
    nums = []
    for n in line:
        nums.append(int(n))

    spisok_for_lvl_1.append(nums)
file.close()
print(spisok_for_lvl_1)
print(nums)
```

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в самой последней вашей строке - если ваш файл пуст, т.е. цикл `for line in file:` не будет выполнен ни одного раза, то и все действия внутри цикла не будут выполнены ни одного раза. Следовательно, переменная `nums` не будет объявлена. Раз не объявлена, то и использовать ее нельзя, о чем и говорит ваша ошибка.

Второе - переменная `nums` лишняя, она не используется вами никак, кроме как временно хранить значения. Ее можно заменить:

```
for line in file:
    line = line.strip().split(',')

    spisok_for_lvl_1.append(list(map(int, line)))
```

Функция [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#map) применит функцию из ее параметра ко всем элементам коллекции. [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#int) - это также функция (а не какой-нибудь волшебный оператор преобразования типов).

Если вы хотите получить последний элемент коллекции - можно воспользоваться отрицательными индексами - отрицательный индекс - это индекс с конца массива:

```
if len(spisok_for_lvl_1):
    print(spisok_for_lvl_1[-1])
```

Если вы извлекаете элемент из массива по индексу - проверки обязательны, даже если вы на 95% уверены, что массив окажется не пуст. Сегодня он не пуст, а завтра окажется пустым и ваше приложение должно работать в любых условиях.

Comment: 1- вместо "переменная не объявлена" (что к Питону не применимо), лучше говорить "переменная не определена"  (имя ни на какой объект не ссылается). 2- `spisok_for_lvl_1 = [list(map(int, line.split(','))) for line in file]` 3- вместо `if len(L):`, в Питоне пишут `if L:` (bool(пустая коллекция) is False)